# Tag cell value based on text and symbol

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have will have following values in Column A; 
A1: 11/5, A2: 11/5R,A3:11/6, A4:11/7, A5:11/5$, A6: 11/5

I want to mark these cells as duplicates in Column 10 if the numbers are same without considering the end symbol: Ex: A1, A2, A5, A6 are duplicates and should mark in Col J1, J2, J5, and J6.

Following code is working only for numbers. it is not accounting the end symbols of the cell value. Any suggestions to modify the code to get the desired output are appreciated.

```
Sub FindDuplicates()

Dim LastRow As Long, matchFoundIndex As Long, iCntr As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For iCntr = 1 To LastRow             ' 1 set the start of the dup looks
    If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
        matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" &    LastRow), 0)
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
             Cells(iCntr, 10) = "Duplicate"
        Else
             Cells(iCntr, 10) = "E"
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last character in the cell should be ignored if it is not a number:

```
Sub FindDuplicates()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To LastRow                          ' 1 set the start of the dup looks
        If Cells(x, 1) <> "" Then

            v = IIf(IsNumeric(Right(Cells(x, 1), 1)), Cells(x, 1), Left(Cells(x, 1), Len(Cells(x, 1)) - 1))
            Cells(x, "J") = IIf(Application.Match(v, Range("A1:A" & LastRow), 0) > 1, "E", "Duplicate")

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: Find Duplicates]

Comment: I use 2007, the code is only work for first two cells(A1. A2), is there anything to be changed.?

Comment: I'm also using 2007.  Is the column formatted as text?  IF you provide a download link, I'll get it working for you.

Comment: You would need to use a  service like Dropbox or Google Drive to host the file.  You could email tistackmail@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks, hope you got the file

Comment: @Kuma Can you resend the file.

Comment: Hope you got it. Thank you